# How to ensure that the axes of both plots are of identical length?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I currently have two plots in tikz. There goes the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{tikz} % To plot almost everything.
\usepackage{pst-3d, tikz-3dplot} % To draw in 3D.

% FIGURES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my plot/.style={thick, smooth, samples=100, domain=0.1:5}, my grid/.style={densely dotted,opacity=0.45, every node/.style={black,opacity=1}}, my axis/.style={latex-latex}]
\draw[my plot] (0,0) plot (\x,{ln(\x)});
\coordinate (start plot) at (0.1,{ln(0.1)});
\coordinate (end plot) at (5,{ln(5)});
\draw[my axis] ([shift={(-0.5cm,0.5cm)}]start plot |- end plot) node[above] {$u(\cdot)$} |- node[coordinate](origin){} ([shift={(0.5cm,-0.5cm)}]start plot -| end plot) node[right] {$\cdot$};
\def\x{0.5}\def\y{4}\def\p{0.55}
\coordinate (Ux) at (\x,{ln(\x)});
\coordinate (Uy) at (\y,{ln(\y)});
\coordinate (Up) at ({\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y},{ln(\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y)});
\draw (Ux) -- coordinate[pos=1-\p] (Up-mid) (Uy);
\path let \p1=(Up-mid), \n1={pow(e,\y1*0.03514)} in (28.4576*\n1,\y1) coordinate (Up-mid2);
\draw[my grid] (Ux) |- node[below]{$x$} (origin) |- node[left]{$u(x)$} cycle;
\draw[my grid] (Uy) |- node[below]{$y$} (origin) |- node[left]{$u(y)$} cycle;
\draw[my grid] (Up) |- node[below, yshift=1.4pt]{$px+(1-p)y$} (origin) |- node[left]{$u(px+(1-p)y)$} cycle;
\draw[my grid] (Up-mid) |- (origin) |- node[left]{$pu(x)+(1-p)u(y)$} cycle;
\draw[my grid] (Up-mid) -- (Up-mid2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my plot/.style={thick, smooth, samples=100, domain=0.1:5.5}, my grid/.style={densely dotted,opacity=0.5, every node/.style={black,opacity=1}}, my axis/.style={latex-latex}]
\draw[my plot] (0,0) plot (\x,{(\x)});
\coordinate (start plot) at (0,{(0)});
\coordinate (end plot) at (5.5,{(5.5)});
\draw[my axis] ([shift={(-0.5cm,0.5cm)}]start plot |- end plot) node[above] {$u(\cdot)$} |- node[coordinate](origin){} ([shift={(0.5cm,-0.5cm)}]start plot -| end plot) node[right] {$\cdot$};
\def\x{0.5}\def\y{4}\def\p{0.55}
\coordinate (Ux) at (\x,{(\x)});
\coordinate (Uy) at (\y,{(\y)});
\coordinate (Up) at ({\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y},{(\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y)});
\draw (Ux) -- coordinate[pos=1-\p] (Up-mid) (Uy);
\path let \p1=(Up-mid), \n1={pow(e,\y1*0.03514)} in (28.4576*\n1,\y1) coordinate (Up-mid2);
\draw[my grid] (Ux) |- node[below,]{$x$} (origin) |- node[left]{$u(x)$} cycle;
\draw[my grid] (Uy) |- node[below]{$y$} (origin) |- node[left]{$u(y)$} cycle;
\draw[my grid] (Up) |- node[below, yshift=1.4pt] {$px+(1-p)y$} (origin) |- node[align=right,xshift=-55.0pt]{$pu(x)+(1-p)u(y)=$\\$=u(px+(1-p)y)$} cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As it can be seen in the output, both plots have axes of different length. **What can I do to make sure that the y-axis and x-axis have the same length in both plots?**

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: I see two ways of doing it (with minimal modifications of the initial code).  Either you change, in the first graph, the corresponding line to `\coordinate (end plot) at (5.5,3.3);`, or, in this same first graph, you modify the y scaling, adding `yscale=1.3` at the end of the global options.

Comment: Thank you for your useful comment. I had realised I could change `coordinate (end plot) at (x,y)`, but hadn't been able to figure the correct values. How did you figure out that (5.5,3.3) are the values I need? Also, I hand't thought of `yscale` at all, but it's a good approach too. Again, though, how did you figure out that the `yscale` value I need is 1.3? I'm trying to see where the math you did is coming from. EDIT: using the `yscale`option yields a more pleasant output, but I don't know the reason why. Any hint?

Comment: Also, the x-axis remains unequal between plots...

Comment: There was no math involved.  I made three or four tries (some sort of exhaustion).  Anyway, your code seems to be much too complicated for the result you are looking for.  In general, I would stay with `tikz`, but this is a problem of taste.  If you try to make it clearer, start by drawing the axes (as simple lines ending with arrows) and plot the two graphs together.  Eventually, you can separate them and have the same dimensions for the coordinate systems.

Comment: Thank you. I finally adopted the `pgfplots` solution proposed by Zarko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pgfplots` is not so hard:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                intersections,
                positioning}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm, height=6cm, % <---
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel={$\cdot$},
    xlabel style={anchor=west},
    ylabel={$u(\cdot)$},
    ylabel style={anchor=south},
    xtick=\empty,   ytick=\empty,
    clip=false
            }
\tikzset{
ddline/.append style = {draw=gray, densely dotted},
         tick/.style = {inner sep=2pt, font=\tiny, align=right}
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
       xmin = 0,
     domain = 0.1:5,
    samples = 100
            ]
\addplot [thick] {ln(\x)};
%
\draw[ddline]   (0.5,0) node[tick,above] {$x$} |- coordinate[pos=0.5] (ux)
                (0,{ln(0.5)})   node[tick,left] {$u(x)$};
\draw[ddline, name path=B]
    (2,0) node[tick,below]    {$px+(1-p)y$} |-
    (0,{ln(2)})   node[tick,left]     {$p(u)x+(1-p)u(y)$};
\draw[ddline]   (4,0) node[tick,below]    {$y$} |- coordinate[pos=0.5] (uy)
                (0,{ln(4)})   node[tick,left]     {$u(y)$};
\draw[name path=A, semitransparent]   (ux) -- (uy);
\draw[name intersections={of=A and B, by=s}, ddline]
    (s) -- (s -| 0,0) node[tick,left] {$u(px+(1-p)y)$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, ymin=0
            ]
\addplot [thick] coordinates {(0.1,0.1) (5,5)};
%
\draw[ddline]
    (0.5,0) node[tick,below] {$x$}          |- (0,0.5) node[tick,left] {$u(x)$}
    (2.0,0) node[tick,below] {$px+(1-p)y$}  |- (0,2.0) node[tick,left] {$p(u)x+(1-p)u(y)=$\\
                                                                        $=u(px+(1-p)y)$}
    (4.0,0) node[tick,below] {$y$}          |- (0,4.0) node[tick,left] {$u(y)$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

or

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line shift={-ln(0.1)}, % <---
       xmin = 0,
     domain = 0.1:5,
    samples = 100
            ]
\addplot [thick] {ln(\x)};
%
\draw[ddline]   
    (0.5,{ln(0.1)}) node[tick,above] {$x$} |- coordinate[pos=0.5] (ux)
    (0,{ln(0.5)})   node[tick,left] {$u(x)$};
\draw[ddline, name path=B]
    (2,{ln(0.1)}) node[tick,below]    {$px+(1-p)y$} |-
    (0,{ln(2)})   node[tick,left]     {$p(u)x+(1-p)u(y)$};
\draw[ddline]   
    (4,{ln(0.1)}) node[tick,below]    {$y$} |- coordinate[pos=0.5] (uy)
    (0,{ln(4)})   node[tick,left]     {$u(y)$};
\draw[name path=A, semitransparent]   (ux) -- (uy);
\draw[name intersections={of=A and B, by=s}, ddline]
    (s) -- (s -| 0,0) node[tick,left] {$u(px+(1-p)y)$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, ymin=0
            ]
\addplot [thick] coordinates {(0.1,0.1) (5,5)};
%
\draw[ddline]
    (0.5,0) node[tick,below] {$x$}          |- (0,0.5) node[tick,left] {$u(x)$}
    (2.0,0) node[tick,below] {$px+(1-p)y$}  |- (0,2.0) node[tick,left] {$p(u)x+(1-p)u(y)=$\\
                                                                        $=u(px+(1-p)y)$}
    (4.0,0) node[tick,below] {$y$}          |- (0,4.0) node[tick,left] {$u(y)$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My and your definition of "not so hard" are clearly not the same. But your solution works as desired and I will thus accept it. I wish there were a solution with tikz (I find its syntax simpler, since I'm not that familiar with pgfplots at all). Thank you.

Comment: @Héctor, `pgfplots` (which is based on `tikz`) is designed for drawing diagrams. So, it has prepared function which simplify to draw them (as `axis`, image size, etc.). The same can be achieved by pure `tikz`, but not so easy. Using it, you need to define the same size axis arrows. I have to admit that I tried to find a solution with pure `tikz`, but I quickly got lost in your MWE. Sorry for that. BTW, if you familiar with `tikz˛than is not so hard to learn `pgfplots` (well, bit have huge manuals :-( ).

Comment: I see --I will try to learn `pgfplots`, then. Unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with `tikz`, and `pgfplots` remains a true mystery to me. For instance, I need to modify the third of your plots to add a vertical dotted line that goes from the intersection between the curve and the dotted line associated with `u(px+(1-p)y)` to the x-axis and I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to do it. I'm at a loss, man.